# Error while building or running ngx-bootstrap tests

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

Doing `npm run tests` on Ubuntu I'm getting the following error:

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/lib/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap'

Answer (score 0):

I solved using:

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/lib/node_modules`

not sure if this is the best solution though.