# Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/npm

Tags: root, sudo, permission-denied, unlink, npm-update

First and foremost I have looked into these previous post for answers: [EACCES: permission denied, unlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166318/eacces-permission-denied-unlink)

[Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/npx'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57814364/error-eacces-permission-denied-unlink-usr-local-bin-npx)

[Error while building or running ngx-bootstrap tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54199698/error-while-building-or-running-ngx-bootstrap-tests)

I do not see the answers I seek in any of these posts, or maybe I am not knowledgable enough to decipher how to use those answers to fix my issue. I am still learning so please, if you are answering my post make sure you explain, so that I may fully grasp what is being done and why. I would appreciate it very much.

In VS Code I was trying to work on a project but needed to update the npm version. See example:

[image: VSCode npm update error]

After researching the f***(pardon my language) out of this, I did the following:

after reading this article: https://flaviocopes.com/npm-fix-missing-write-access-error/
I did what he suggested and then tried to do the npm update.

[image: missing write error - fix]

I then did the following, to find who owns the directory

[image: npm error 2]

After this I am pretty much at lost of what to do next, why do I have three 'drwxr-xr-x'? what does that exactly mean, that I have three npm packages? can I combine them all into one? or would it be better to delete all and start from scratch, but would I run into the same issue?

I also read this:

> To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to
>   use a different directory. In this example, you will create and use a
>   hidden directory in your home directory.
>
> Back up your computer. On the command line, in your home directory,
>   create a directory for global installations: mkdir ~/.npm-global
>   Configure npm to use the new directory path: npm config set prefix
>   '~/.npm-global' In your preferred text editor, open or create a
>   ~/.profile file and add this line: export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
>   On the command line, update your system variables: source ~/.profile
>   To test your new configuration, install a package globally without
>   using sudo

but will that work if I have to [unlink '/usr/local/bin/npm'], according to the terminal. In all honestly, I prefer not reconfigure as I would need to back up everything, does anyone have a solution or suggestion as to what to do?

Thank you all in advance. And again I would like to reiterate that I am still learning, so please be kind and elaborate on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

See if you have another path setup

like **

> /usr/local/share/npm/bin

**
or so and just run install like this below.

**

> sudo npm install npm@latest -g

**